# List-Then-Eliminate implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement the List-Then-Eliminate algorithm using a dataset. However, I am getting the wrong vector space at the end. I am unable to figure out what the issue is.

Basically, I iterate through all the training instances. For each hypothesis, I use the last 5 bits to check if the training instance, `x` is the same and then compare the `c(x)`

Any assistance would be appreciated. Below is my code.

```
def gen_vector_space(k):
    return [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('01', repeat=k)]

#basically values from 0-65536 in binary
vector_space = gen_vector_space(pow(2,4)) 

for train_inst in train_data:

result = train_inst[-1]
d = train_inst[:-1]

for h in vector_space:
    if h[-5:-1] == d:
        if (h[-1] != result):
            vector_space.remove(h)
print(len(vector_space))
```

Comment: You don't want to modify any mutable data structure while iterating over it, bad things happen to those who do

Comment: Also, where is `vector_space` defined?

Comment: I've edited the code above to include my vector space. It's basically a list of strings which represent the number from 0-65536 in binary form, i.e.; 00000..,....1111111....

Comment: is `gen_vector_space` a function you defined? because you could probably do this checking there if so. That way you aren't going through the space twice

Comment: yes. I wrote the function and it basically returns the list. What type of checking?

Comment: Can you add that code to the question? You are generating a list of values and returning it. Instead of calling `.remove(val)` on `vector_space`, you could just not include them in the `vector_space` at all. *Or* you could reformat the function to give you a generator

Comment: Added the code. Wouldn't the same issue come up even then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188909/discussion-between-user782400-and-c-nivs).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest an edit to the function that creates your vector space. Starting with your original function:

```py
def create_space(k):
    return [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('01', repeat=k)]
```

When you call that function, you are completely iterating over that range to build the list, then iterating the list *again* to filter out values. Two approaches to fix that:

### If statements in function

```py
# Redefine your function to only return values that matter to you

def create_space(k, d, result):
    """
    This will filter out your limits, takes result and d as params
    """
    vector_space = []

    for x in itertools.product('01', repeat=k):
        if x[-5:-1]==d and x[-1]!= result:
            vector_space.append(x)

    return vector_space

# define k, d, and result here

vector_space = create_space(k, d, result)
```

### Generator Approach

Or, the `yield` keyword will calculate values one at a time, so you are only iterating once:

```py
def create_space(k):
    for x in itertools.product('01', repeat=k):
        yield x


vector_space = []

# define d and result here

for x in create_space(k):
    if x[-5:-1]==d and x[-1]!= result:
        vector_space.append(x)
```

The thing to note with either of these approaches is that I'm not editing an already established object while iterating over it. Instead, I've put the filtering on before the space is created, that way you get exactly what you want on the first go.